# Checking for open ports on a remote server using sockets hangs when the port is closed, C

Tags: c, sockets

I wrote a simple application which connects to a given server on a given port. When the port is open, everything is ok, I got the message about the established connection. However, when the port is closed, nothing happens, my program does not show me the information about it.

I test my program using my remote server accessible via the Internet. How can I improve this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char * ip_addr;
    int port;

    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;

    if (argc != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Usage: ./canconnect ip port\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    ip_addr = argv[1];
    port = atoi(argv[2]);

    if (port <= 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"error: invalid port\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    inet_aton(ip_addr, &server_addr.sin_addr);

    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1)
    {
        perror("connect");
        printf("Port %d is closed on server %s.\n", port, ip_addr);
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Connection established. Port %d is open on server %s.\n", port, ip_addr);
    }

    close(sockfd);

    return 0; }
```

Comment: Looks like the program's waiting for the timeout to occur.

Comment: @ForceBru: Can I do something about it?

Comment: Does it hang for a very long time or it shows some info after a few seconds or minutes?

Comment: @ForceBru: It shows some information after a while, but its not the most efficient solution for me, because I need to make a very simple port scanner (http://pastie.org/private/isldfmssjbkpdye4n3tt3q) and it would take a lot of time to check all the available ports with this code ...

Comment: Scan all ports at the same time.  Launch as many processes as scanned port, one process per port. Or, if using nonblocking sockets, you can do the same within one process, however, this will be more difficult to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the program actually prints some data after some time, it's most certainly has to do with *timeout*.

In order to finally decide that the host or the port is unreadable or the connection couldn't be established for any other reason, `connect` performs several attempts to connect and returns an error after a certain amount of time - the *timeout*.

The value of timeout can be changed to any value you want using [`setsockopt`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=setsockopt&sektion=2):

```
struct timeval timeout;      
timeout.tv_sec = 3; // wait for three seconds
timeout.tv_usec = 0;

// set up receive timeout
if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *)&timeout,
            sizeof(timeout)) < 0)
    printf("[!] setsockopt failed\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

If the remote server is reachable, but neither accepts nor refuses the connection, then `connect()` will block until the network connection attempt times out.  As [the Linux manual page for `connect`(2)](https://linux.die.net/man/2/connect) puts it:

> Note that for IP sockets the timeout may be very long when syncookies are enabled on the server.

Indeed, it is a well-known defense against port scans to attempt to elicit that behavior intentionally.  You might be able to get quicker failures by using `setsockopt()` to set a receive timeout, but the docs are inconsistent on whether that will work for `connect()`.